# Connect to postgres with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im struggling to create API call to my database from node.js.
i have a postgres instance on Centos with multiple databases and table.
im trying to get table name "test_reslts" from database "sizing_results".
when the url, its just the server ip and port like http://{SERVER IP}:3300/
this is output -
"Cannot GET /"
when adding the table name or db name and table name, the request isn't completed and not output.

my code -
**db_connection**

```
const {Client} = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
  user: 'postgres',
  database: 'sizing_results',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
  host: 'localhost',
})

module.exports = client
```

**api.js**

```
const client = require('./db_connection.js')
const express = require('express'); // To make API calls 
const app = express();

app.listen(3300, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is now listening at port 3300");
})

client.connect();

app.get('/test_results', (req, res)=>{
    client.query(`select * from test_results`, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send('BLABLA')
            res.send(result.rows);
        }
    });
    client.end;
})
```

Comment: The message "Cannot Get/" make me think that it might be a nodejs/http problem.
Do you reach your routre ?
If you put a console.log before your "client.query" does it print something ?
If no it's more a nodeJS problem

Comment: No, no any print.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your answer to my comment I think it's not a DB connection problem.

It seems to be link to your routing, because it seems node never reach the inside of your route.

Are you sure you are calling the good route (http://localhost:3300/test_results) with no typo ? And with the good protocol (GET) ?

Comment: Yes, im sure, when im running the following script to get all the data, without get request, im getting all the data.
const {Client} = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
  user: 'postgres',
  database: 'sizing_results',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
  host: 'localhost',
})
client.connect();

/*
client.query('Select * from test_results', (err, res)=>{
 if(!err){
  console.log(res.rows);
 } else {
  console.log(err.message);
 }
 client.end;
})
*/

Comment: Yes I think your DB request is fine.
But I think your http request isn't.
If you try to add another route with no specific path like this :
```app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('Hello')
})```
And then run your http request.
If "Hello" isn't printed it means that you are probable using the wrong URL.

Sadly, I'm not an expert in vanilla express, so if it's not a wrong url, I don't see where it comes from. Your projet really look like the example project given by express.

Comment: Just to be sure can you give us the http call you are doing ?